# Randomize my public IP

Tags: ip

For some reasons, I want my computer/Local Area Network to have a different IP each time when I visit Google, or any other website. How can I do that without

1. Restarting the router?
2. Use different VPN providers?

Comment: [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use a Proxy rotator/randomizer. A proxy is a server that all your traffic is send through before reaching the real destination. The outside only sees the Proxy's IP.
2. Instead of restarting the router, it's also possible to just reconnect to your provider. Should be considerably faster, but still comes with short connection-loss.
3. Use Tor (or some kind of other anonymisation network) - you can think of Tor as a "encrypted and randomized Proxy network".

I think other than these possibilities do not exist (unless you are your own ISP and own an IP range).

Comment: Thanks, you have any Proxy rotator that you can recommend?

Comment: @Graviton, No sorry, I don't use one. Also depends on your browser and operating system. There exist Firefox plugins however.